# admin grid action column caption show original data

Tags: grid

I want to show the caption as database return value

```
    $this->addColumn('quota_item_id', array(
        'header'    => $helper->__('quota_item_id@sales_flat_quota_item'),
        'align'     =>'left',
        'width'     => '20%',
        'index'     => 'quota_item_id',
        'type'      => 'action',
        'getter'    => 'getQuota_item_id',          
        'actions'   => array(
            array(
                'caption'   => $this->getQuota_item_id(),
                'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                'field'     => 'id',
                'onclick' => "return popitup('".$this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getQuota_item_id()))."')"
            )
        ),
    ));
```

`'caption'   => $this->getQuota_item_id()`, Shows nothing, anyone know how to fix it?